# Using facebook graph API 2.5 for batch request in Java

Tags: java, facebook-graph-api

I was using facebook FQL query to fetch sharecount for multiple URLS using this code without needing any access token.

```
 https://graph.facebook.com/fql?q=";
    "SELECT url, total_count,share_count FROM link_stat WHERE url in (";  

       private void callFB(List validUrlList,Map> dataMap,long timeStamp,Double calibrationFactor){
        try {
            StringBuilder urlString = new StringBuilder();
            System.out.println("List Size " + validUrlList.size());
            for (int i = 0; i < (validUrlList.size() - 1); i++) {
                urlString.append("\"" + validUrlList.get(i) + "\",");
            }
            urlString.append("\""
                    + validUrlList.get(validUrlList.size() - 1) + "\"");
            String out = getConnection(fbURL+URLEncoder.encode(
                    queryPrefix
                            + urlString.toString() + ")", "utf-8"));
            dataMap = getSocialPopularity(validUrlList.toArray(), dataMap);
            getJSON(out, dataMap, timeStamp,calibrationFactor);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

But as now Facebook has depreciated it i am planning to use
https://graph.facebook.com/v2.5/?ids=http://timesofindia.indiatimes.com/life-style/relationships/soul-curry/An-NRI-bride-who-was-tortured-to-hell/articleshow/50012721.cms&access_token=abc
But i could not find any code to make batch request in the same also i am using pageaccesstoken so what could be the rate limit for same.
Could you please help me to find teh batch request using java for this new version.

Comment: So, you're posting the more or less same question twice with two accounts?

Answer (score 0):

You will *always* be subject to rate limiting... If you're using the `/?ids=` endpoint, there's already a "batch" functionality built-in.

See

- https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/using-graph-api/v2.5#multirequests
- https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/advanced/rate-limiting